# How to merge git repositories in subfolders without losing branches and tags?

Tags: git, git-merge, monorepo

While this question would seem to be a duplicate or many previous ones (and tens of blog posts dealing with similar subject), I need to make you aware that I am looking for an approach that would allow me to script it.

- all branches and tags are supposed to merged
- branches and tags are supposed to be prefixed in order to avoid overlapping
- files would not overlap because we import to a new subfolder.
- Incremental merge process: be able to merge new repositories later as I plan to migrate to a monorepo setup slowly, one repository at a time.

The script I am trying to build should work like this:

```
./merge-repo monorepo/subdir/foo git@github.com:example/foo.git
```

This would assume that the target repository (monorepo) is already cloned inside `monorepo/` folder and that it does not have any local changes.

For example if the foo.git would have two branches `master` and `develop` and one tag names `v1.0`, after performing the merge, I would expect to see branches `foo-master` and `foo-develop` and the tag `foo-v1.0` inside monorepo repository.

I read tens of articles (or scripts) but so far I was not able to find one that explains how can I obtain this.

### Clarifications

- If I do have a README.txt inside the root of the foo.git repo, I would expect to see this file inside `monorepo/subdir/foo/README.txt`. That's the only approach that would allow me to merge repositories without conflicts, if these are going to become subdirectories of the big repo (subdirectories that did not exist before).

### Update

While I am not ready yet to say that the issue is solved, I ended up writing this bash script that is supposed to perform the merge after patching the source repository. Have a look at it https://github.com/ssbarnea/monorepo/blob/master/git-monorepo-add.sh

PS. I will be back with a proper answer as soon I do have a reliable solution, tested with many repositories.

Comment: Did you mean `foo-v1.0`?

Comment: What should happen with the branches after the root directories are “merged”? Should the new directory structure be commited to some global `master` branch? Should all the `master` refs fetched from other repositories point to this new commit?

Comment: Well, anyway, I’ll just point out that you can do `git read-tree --prefix=foo/ <ref>` followed by `git checkout-index -f -a` in order to create a new directory `foo` which will contain all the files from a tree-ish (commit, branch, tag).

Comment: In fact I do want to merge foo/master into master and I do expect the developers to be able to continue to use their foo/dev-branch. Still, I do think it is unavoidable to ask them to merge master into their branch before doing any work, otherwise their foo/dev-branch would contain only their sub-project, without the rest.

Comment: Well, again, since I have no idea why you are doing this, it’s hard to give a reasonable advice, but you should be able continuously do the `read-tree --prefix` trick to keep your mega-master up to date with other masters. Other people will just continue to commit to their repositories knowing nothing about your mega-repository. And you won’t be able to preserve any kind of history this way, of course.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: I do not expect to continue to use old-repositories after we migrate them to monorepo. This means that there is no requirement for being able to merge things back into them. In fact we will probably make them read-only one by one right after we migrate them. Still, developers explained the need to be able to keep the entire history as part of the migration, so they could dig the history.

Comment: In this case the only solution I see is to iterate over all the branches in the remote repository and integrate them into the corresponding mega-branch by doing `read-tree --prefix` and then recording this as a handcrafted merge commit (using `git commit-tree`) between the remote branch and mega-branch. After that all the files will seem to be just moved into the subdirectory after that merge, and all the history before the merge will be preserved (although with old paths, of course).

Comment: It is very much not clear how to integrate tags in this scenario. Probably just scope them without changing targets.

Answer (score 4):

You can pull a remote repositories branches and tags into namespaced (i.e., `<prefix>`) refs with something like:

```
git fetch --no-tags <url> \
    refs/heads/*:refs/heads/<prefix>/* \
    refs/tags/*:refs/tags/<prefix>/*
```

With your example, this would give you branches `foo/master` and `foo/develop` and a tag named `foo/v1.0`.  Not exactly what you asked for, but maybe that's fine.  Note that `--no-tags` is specified to avoid fetching tags into the "global" namespace.

At this point you probably want to merge one of these branches into you local repo's master.  Here is one way to go about this:

```
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit foo/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=foo/ -u foo/master
$ git commit -m "merged in `master' from project foo"
```

Comment: Using `slash` instead of `dash` would not be a problem at all, as I stated that was an example in order to assure that I do not have overlappings. Still, I will need to assure that I merge all of these into a subfolder of the target repository. So far my impression is that I will have to prepare the source repository  before I do the merge. By prepare, I mean to alter all its history so it would use the target subdirectory.

Comment: @sorin It’s not entirely clear what you mean by merging directories. Do you want to somehow merge the directory trees form e.g. the `master` branches or what?

Comment: @kirelagin I updated the question. Cchris solved one important question that I had: the rename of the branches and tags so they do not overlap. Now I only have to deal with the subdirectory part.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to do two things:

1. Import all the underlying git objects.
2. Merge user-facing structure of the repositories (branches, tags, etc.)

You do the former by simply `fetch`ing all the branches and tags of the remote repository. Since the objects are indexed by hashes, taking the union is a trivial task, you have to do nothing.

At this point you have all the necessary objects inside your repository. You’ve got all the remote branches, and you can list them e.g. by running `git branch -r --list '<remote_name>/*'` (actually, you don’t have to do anything if you are ok with this name pattern).

Tags, as far as I can tell, are a little bit trickier. They are not scoped by remotes, so you can’t just fetch them all together and rename later. This means, you’ll have to manually obtain the list of tags (`git ls-remote --tags <remote_name>`), iterate over them creating the ones with altered names and fetch.